# Setting specific values to 0 in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two arrays (`gt` and `pred`) with values ranging from 0 to 4.

The shape of these two arrays is `(1, 1, 93, 349, 219)`. My target is to create a mask to ignore and multiplying it into gt and pred to ignore the value in two arrays. However, I am facing an issue

```
ignore_value=4
if ignore_value is not None:
    mask[gt!=ignore_value]=1  # ignore value mask
    gt=mask*gt
    pred=mask*pred  # ignore value mask for pred


print "after removing ignore value: ", np.unique(gt),np.unique(pred)
output: after removing ignore value:  [0 1 2 3] [0 1 2 3 4]
```

why it is not removing the ignore value in `pred`?

Comment: How did you initialise `mask`?

Comment: @coldspeed `mask=np.zeros(gt.shape, dtype=np.int32)`

Comment: Other thing, is this code being called inside a function that you passed these arrays to?

Comment: @coldspeed yes, gt, pred, and ignore_value are input arguments passed to the function

Comment: why it is acting on `gt` but not `pred`?!

Comment: Ah, okay. I get it. You initialised a mask based on gt, but pred may not necessarily have 4s in the same cells as gt does. Bottom line, you need two separate masks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, a better solution would be to use boolean indexing and explicitly set cells to 0.

```
gt[gt == ignore_value] = 0
pred[pred == ignore_value] = 0
```

In general, it is not guaranteed that `gt` and `pred` will have `ignore_value` in the same cells, so using a single mask for both of them is not appropriate.

However, the code above works and is more efficient because it is only operating on a small portion of the array, not all of it (as multiplying them would do). The is the output

Comment: thank you for your help, what if I write like this:
`gt=np.where(gt==ignore_value,0,gt)
            pred=np.where(pred==ignore_value,0,pred)`

Comment: @S.EB It will work, but will generate a new array. It is not as efficient.